# Only new content fade in, not all the content?

Tags: jquery

for some reason this doesn't work and i am trying to make only the next content fade in rather than everything fade in with new content each time..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".load_more").click(function (){
        $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                var newPost = $(html);
                if(newPost.length){
                    newPost.hide().appendTo(".main_page").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                }else{
                    $('.load_more').replaceWith('There are no more posts.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How do i treat the "html" as a jquery object (DOM), then make it animated?

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of html?

Comment: it doesn't do anything.. before i added all the fading effect (or tried to) it was simply adding posts until it ran out of data but now it doesn't react

Comment: you should try to see what value it holds. Try console.log(html). You are using it as a selector, it must have something.

Comment: not entirely sure how to do that.. could you post that as an answer here?

Comment: Added it as an answer. If it goes to the "success" condition, it should have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested, try making the html parameter show up its value by using:

```
console.log(html);
```

or

```
alert(html);
```

Comment: <div class="ad_display" id="'.$date.'">
       <a href="post.php?id='. $id .'"><img src="' . $cover . '" alt=" " class="ad_cover"></a>
       <div class="'. $status .'">$' . number_format($price) . '</div>       
      </div>

Comment: obviously the $cover and $price are replaced with numbers. and there are 10 more divs all look similar as thats what supposed to follow

Comment: That's the output of html?

Comment: well i placed the alert(html); in the if statement so yeah

Comment: You really think this line of code here <div class="ad_display" id="'.$date.'"> can be used as a selector?

Comment: Why don't you just echo their ids?

Comment: Then what's the output if you just echo the ids?

Comment: by echo their id you mean just do echo $date? how can i say id=$date?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47467/discussion-between-bamba-and-witherwind)